# Integrate a Valued Table Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Thanks to help on this forum I was made aware of using a valued table function to get a declare function working in a way so that it can later be used to create a view.
I just don't know how to connect the dots.
The valued table function looks like:

```
USE [m_DEV]
GO

--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO

--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO

--CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Entries] AS

    CREATE FUNCTION [Manual_COUNTRIES_2019]()
    RETURNS TABLE
    RETURN
        SELECT *
        FROM (       
       VALUES --risk_1
            (1,'AX'),(1,'AY'),(1,'AQ'),(1,'BQ')
            --risk_2 
            ,(2,'AA'),(2,'AI'),(2,'AX')
            -- @risk_3 
            ,(3,'QE'),(3,'QT')
            -- @risk_4 
            ,(4,'AA'),(4,'AB'),(4,'AS'),(4,'AZ')
            -- @risk_5 
            ,(5,'BB'),(5,'BC'),(5,'CD')
    
         ) AS X (RiskNum, Code);
       RETURN
     END;

    
    WITH Lead AS (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from 1 ) THEN '0'   
                WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from 2 ) THEN '0.5'   
                WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from 3 ) THEN '1'   
                WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from 4 ) THEN '2'   
                WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code from 5 ) THEN '3'
            END AS 'risk_country1'        
        FROM  [dbo].[Manual_Entries_19] a
    )
```

How do you connect `(RiskNum, Code)` with `IN (SELECT Code from 1 )`
I tried different variations. Do I need to call the function-table: `[Manual_COUNTRIES_2019]`? But how?

Where does the `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Entries] AS` need to sit in relation to the   `CREATE FUNCTION [Manual_COUNTRIES_2019]()` ? - I doubt it will work the way it currently sits.

Comment: What is the "object" `1`? If you *did* have a object named `1` you would *have* to delimit identify it, as object names that start with a numerical value must be (`[1]`)`. Though, honestly, if you *do* have some objects named, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc, I **strongly** suggest you rename those.

Comment: Also, you declare a CTE, and then `SELECT` from it; the above SQL appears to be incomplete. Side note as well, `a` as an alias for `Manual_Entries_19` makes little sense. `ME19` would be far clearer. I also hope that you don't have tables like `Manual_Entries_1`, `Manual_Entries_2`, `Manual_Entries_18`, as then you have a severely denormalised database you should be looking to fix as well.

Comment: @Lamu, thank you for the comments. No worries, all tables names and values are adjusted and changed so that I can present it on Stack overflow without revealing too much. So, yea, they actually all have other names. All good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the values from your TVF as follows:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.Manual_COUNTRIES_2019() WHERE RiskNum = 1) THEN '0'   
    WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.Manual_COUNTRIES_2019() WHERE RiskNum = 2) THEN '0.5'   
    WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.Manual_COUNTRIES_2019() WHERE RiskNum = 3) THEN '1'   
    WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.Manual_COUNTRIES_2019() WHERE RiskNum = 4) THEN '2'   
    WHEN a.[10_2_1_Country] IN (SELECT Code FROM dbo.Manual_COUNTRIES_2019() WHERE RiskNum = 5) THEN '3'
END AS 'risk_country1'
```

Comment: Beautiful, it worked all very well, and I have me view tables now. Thank you for this 1:1! Learnt heaps!